# C# Process cmd.exe - 'hadoop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c#, iis, cmd, local-system-account

Okay, I will give you the context first.

1. I have a website deployed in IIS 7.
2. On the server, I have windows Mapr Client installed. This gives me an access to the hadoop clusters on the windows system. ([Windows MAPR client installation](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Setting+Up+the+Client))
3. I have logged on and checked that the hadoop client is working properly.

So now the problem.

I am using the C# Process and ProcessStartInfo classes to open an instance of the cmd.exe where I get the file from the hadoop server and make it accessible on the UI. (hadoop fs -get ..... ).
But for some reason, the error that I collected from process.StandardError returns the error below:

**'hadoop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I checked that the user that is running the cmd process is the one of the administrators of the server.

Things to note: The command prompt working directory is 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv'. Does this mean its a 32 bit cmd ? May be thats a reason hadoop is not recognized ? I thought of replicating the issue. (opening a 32 bit cmd prompt and typing hadoop for that admin user. But the hadoop command worked successfully)

I don't understand here why hadoop command is not recognized for this high privileged user.

UPDATE:

This seems to be a similar issue. I will give it a try and let you know.

[Process.Start cmd.exe won't run cmd file that is passed as agument when running in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590924/process-start-cmd-exe-wont-run-cmd-file-that-is-passed-as-agument-when-running)

OK this is not the same issue. As I am able to open and run the batch file.
But the cmd doesnt recognize the commands I have installed.

So the question would be, what version of cmd it actually starts ? By version, I mean the cmd that doesnt have anything installed in it ?

Answer (score 0):

32 Bit processes look in

- c:\windows\syswow64 when asking for c:\windows\System32
- c:\windows\system32 when asking for c:\windows\sysnative

and 64 bit processes look in

- c:\windows\system32 when asking for c:\windows\system32
- c:\windows\syswow64 when asking for c:\windows\syswow64
- generate an error when asking for c:\windows\sysnative

Comment: I am not even sure if its a 32 bit or 64 bit issue.